# Swift protocol property set not executed

Tags: swift, swift-protocols

I try to use the set method for calling a function after the value is changed.

I did not see why the set method is not called.

The code could be directly executed in playground

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit

protocol RandomItem {
    var range : (Int,Int) {get set}
    var result : Int {get set}

    init()
    mutating func createRandom()
}

extension RandomItem {
    var range : (Int,Int) {
        get {
            return range
        }
        set {
            range = newValue
            self.createRandom()
        }
    }
}

struct Item: RandomItem {
    var range =  (0,1)
    var result: Int = 0

    init() {
        self.createRandom()
    }

    mutating func createRandom() {
        let low = UInt32(range.0)
        let high = UInt32(range.1)
        result = Int(arc4random_uniform(high - low + 1) + low)
    }
}
```

Comment: The extension accessors both perform an infinite recursive call. That seems bogus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your struct `Item` declares its own `range` property, which overrides the default you created in the protocol extension.  The `range` property in `Item` has no getters or setters defined to do what your extension version does.

Another issue:

Your protocol extension defines the `range` property as a computed property (no storage) whose getter and setter both call itself. This will loop infinitely.

Maybe you are looking for something more like:

```
protocol RandomItem {
    var storedRange: (Int, Int) { get }
    var range : (Int,Int) {get set}
    var result : Int {get set}

    init()
    mutating func createRandom()
}

extension RandomItem {
    var range : (Int,Int) {
        get {
            return storedRange
        }
        set {
            storedRange = newValue
            self.createRandom()
        }
    }
}

struct Item: RandomItem {
    var result: Int = 0
    var storedRange = (0, 1)

    init() {
        self.createRandom()
    }

    mutating func createRandom() {
        let low = UInt32(range.0)
        let high = UInt32(range.1)
        result = Int(arc4random_uniform(high - low + 1) + low)
    }
}
```

This requires a conforming type to define a stored property `storedRange`, which the default implementation of the computed property `range` will interact with.

Comment: Item does have (autogenerated) accessors which override those inherited from the protocol.

Comment: I had to extend the storedRange variable with a set option, but then I works as expected. Thanks